# How to update an existing value in the Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would to update an existing value in my Firebase Realtime Database. I have tried several ways but none have worked. Anyone know how can I fix it? I attach the structure of the db if it can be useful and the code I have written so far. Thanks in advance to everyone

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users");

myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.getValue() != null) {
            //loop through the keys
            Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            for(DataSnapshot datasnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                if(datasnap.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(email)) {

                    hashMap.put("address", "TEST1");

                    myRef.child(email).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, "Data successfully update",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the wrong location in the database, which means that either the write is now showing up in the screenshot *or* it is rejected (which your code doesn't handle).

To update the `address` of the child node you're looping over:

```
myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot datasnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            datasnap.child("address").getRef().setValue("TEST1").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, "Data successfully update",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

The key change here is that I call `getRef()` on the snapshot, to get a reference to that specific location in the database.

You'll note that I also removed the two conditions, since neither of them had any effect on the outcome.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but in this way the code inside the onChange() is completely skipped.

Comment: The only change is inside the `onDataChange`. I changed nothing about how the listener is attached, so if `onDataChange` was triggered before it should be triggered with this change too.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore ff = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            ff.collection("myCollection")
                    .document(myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .update("field",value)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                //for example Toast.makeText(context,getString(R.string.user_updated),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```